# Angular Material mat-form-field modifies styling of toolbar

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Trying to create an input field in my component where I have `mat-toolbar` element, unfortunately inserting a `mat-form-field` element changes the styling of the `mat-toolbar`.

I was not able to diagnose where the issue is coming from (maybe if you happen to find out it will be a good idea to explain how you did), nor how to overcome it.

Here is a stackblitz minified example. To make the bug appear - uncomment line 11 in `/test-comp.component.html`. [Link to StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5vtrls?file=src/app/test-comp/test-comp.component.html)

**Note:** I know a simple border can be used instead of `border-box` class but in the full-blown app it serves a different purpose that I can not replicate with a border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mat-form-field` without any form field control, and hence the issue. You can try adding any form field control and it will work. As an example, we can add `<input>` element along with `matInput` directive as:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>
```

We also would have to import appropriate module in app.module.ts:

```ts
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
...
 imports: [
  ...
  MatInputModule
 ]
```

> I was not able to diagnose where the issue is coming from (maybe if you happen to find out it will be a good idea to explain how you did), nor how to overcome it.

I went to Stackblitz, uncommented the line and was surprised with the output. Since I haven't used Angular Material Components, I tried to investigate styles within Devtool Elements tab. I didn't saw anything wrong with the styles. I opened the console and there it was:

```
Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
```

That gave me the clue that mat-form-field should have some kind of form control within it. I went to the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol), and found this:

> This error occurs when you have not added a form field control to your form field. If your form field contains a native  or <textarea> element, make sure you've added the matInput directive to it and have imported MatInputModule. Other components that can act as a form field control include <mat-select>, <mat-chip-list>, and any custom form field controls you've created.

**PS:** I was also able to see below warning in console. So you may need to add theme too.

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming